# htaccess rewriterule. I don't want all of them rewritten - How to exclude some pages?

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^moreinfo/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/moreinfo$1 [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^healthsolutions/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/healthsolutions$1 [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1/ [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I am now using wordpress rather than straight html coding. The rewriterules above work to forward all of the old .html and .htm pages in the root directory and in /moreinfo/ and /healthsolutions/ directories. Unfortunately they also strip .htm and .html from wordpress pages (I thought they all ended in php initially). Now I see some of the basic functions like opening up the image editor in the visual editor of wordpress end in .html (using them produces a 404 error).

So the question is: is there any way to restrict my rewriterules to certain directories, so Wordpress functions are not hindered?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

RewriteEngine On

```
# assuming wordpress is installed in blog directory
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*|)$ - [L] # don't take any action

RewriteRule ^moreinfo/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/moreinfo$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^healthsolutions/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/healthsolutions$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: well Wordpress is installed in the root directory as well as many of the redirects, but I believe all functions I am trying allow (like editing an image are in the wp-content folder. So if I replace "blog" above with wp-content, will it have the same effect?

Comment: Hmm in that case it won't be easy because WP needs all requests to go through its root `index.php` anyway. I will try to find a solution on my WP installation tomorrow.

Comment: I added the exclusion above for the folders /wp-content/, /wp-admin/, and /wp-includes/ and it works perfectly, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a Rewrite condition, such as this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(dontrewrite\.php)
```

You can add RegEx expressions in there to omit certain directories/folders/filetypes.